# How to upload/save and show pictures with Mongoose,Express, Angular 4 and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose

I am using Mongoose, Express, **Angular 4** and NodeJS to create an app, and I am quite new to the language.
In one of my components I have a CRUD that I would like to upload a picture.
After saving it to Mongoose/MongoDB, I want to show the picture on the screen.

Should I use a plugin? If so, which one?  Can you post an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to upload file to server, you can use multer module for nodejs which is available with npm.

This site will be very helpful for you.
- https://www.terlici.com/2015/05/16/uploading-files-locally.html

And, if you want use multer with mongoose, this example will be also helpful.

`Image.js`

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const Image = new Schema({
  filename: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  originalname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}, {timestamps: true})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', Image)
```

`server.js`

```
// ...
const app = express()
const Image = require('./Image.js')
const multer = require('multer')
const path = require('path')
const UPLOAD_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/uploadedFiles')
const upload = multer({
  dest: UPLOAD_PATH,
  limits: {fileSize: 1000000, files: 5}
})

// upload image
app.post('/api/image', upload.array('image', 5), (req, res, next) => {
  const images = req.files.map((file) => {
    return {
      filename: file.filename,
      originalname: file.originalname
    }
  })
  Image.insertMany(images, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(404)
    res.json(result)
  })
})

// get image with id
app.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  Image.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, (err, image) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(404)
    fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(UPLOAD_PATH, image.filename)).pipe(res)
  })
})

// ...
```

`client.js`

```
// ...
const axios = require('axios')

function uploadImage () {
  const files = document.getElementById('INPUT_TAG').files
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('image', files[0])
  axios.post('YOUR_URL/api/image', formData)
}
// ...
```

`upload.html`

```
<body>
  <input type="file" id="INPUT_TAG"/>
  <button>call uploadImage() with angular/vue/react/etc</button>
</body>
```

`image.html`

```
<body>
  <img src="YOUR_URL/api/image/IMAGE_ID">
</body>
```